# Adding a title based on a value in an *ngFor / *ngIf

Tags: angular

Unable to find a solution to my problem, I ask my question here.

I am retrieving a list of object from my database. Each fruit contains these values : Id, Name, Image, Code and Color.

I would like to display a title for each fruit color.

In my example, I'm getting 2 red fruits and 1 blue fruit. So I would like to get a title "RED" with the 2 red fruits below, and a title "BLUE" with the blue fruit below.

[What I'm looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2BBU.png)

This is what I managed to do :

```html
  <div class="col-md-10 offset-md-1 row d-flex justify-content-center after-loop">
    <div *ngFor="let fruit of fruits$;">
      <div *ngIf="fruit.color == 'red'">
        <h3 style="color:#fff"><span style="color:#ea4848">COLOR</span> - Red</h3>
        <div *ngIf="active">
          <app-fruit [name]="fruit.name" [image]="fruit.image" [code]="fruit.code"
            [color]="fruit.color"></app-fruit>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[My result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhlCz.png)

If the fruit is red, it will print a title above the fruit card. I'm more looking for a "global" title.

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest grouping your array with `reduce` in accordance to their colors first and get instance on your colors array for us to be able to loop over in the grouped fruits

Have created a **[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-group-list?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/app.component.html)** for your reference

**Component**

```
// Group the fruits by their colors
this.groupedFruits = this.fruits
   .reduce((box, fruit) => {
      box[fruit.color] = box[fruit.color] ?  [ ...box[fruit.color], fruit ] : [ fruit ];
      return box;
}, {});

// Grab all the color keys inside your groupedFruits array
this.colors = Object.keys(this.groupedFruits);
```

Your `groupedFruits`'s data will then be like this when grouped:

```
{ 
  red: [{ name: 'apple' }, { name: 'strawberry'}],
  yellow: [{ name: 'mango' }],
  ...and so on
}
```

**Template**

```
<ul *ngFor="let color of colors">
   // Color Name with count of how many fruits under that color
   <h4 class="ml-0">
      {{ color }} 
      <span class="badge badge-secondary">{{ groupedFruits[color].length }}</span>
   </h4>

   // loop the fruits according to their color
   <li *ngFor="let fruit of groupedFruits[color]">{{ fruit.name }}</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd first have to categorize them in your source data:

This is some custom code, because I can't see your actual data retrieving implementation:

If you have something like this in your component code:

```
readonly fruits$: Observable<Fruit[]> = this.getFruits().pipe(
  shareReplay({ refCount: true, bufferSize: 1 })
);

readonly fruitCats$: Observable<{color: string, fruits: Fruit[]}[]> = this.fruits$.pipe(
  map((fruits) => fruits.reduce((cats, fruit) => {
    const cat = cats.find(({ color }) => fruit.color === color);

    cat ? cat.fruits.push(fruit) : cats.push({ color: fruit.color, fruits: [ fruit ] });

    return cats;
  }, []),
  shareReplay({ refCount: true, bufferSize: 1 })
);
```

Then you can do the following in your template:

```
<div class="col-md-10 offset-md-1 row d-flex justify-content-center after-loop">
  <div *ngFor="let fruitCat of fruitCats$ | async">
    <div *ngIf="fruitCat.color == 'red'">
      <h3 style="color:#fff"><span style="color:#ea4848">COLOR</span> - Red</h3>
    </div>

    <div *ngFor="let fruit of fruitCat.fruits">
      <app-fruit [name]="fruit.name" [image]="fruit.image"
                [code]="fruit.code" [color]="fruit.color"></app-fruit>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Another option would be to write a custom pipe, to categorize your array by a certain property, but I'll leave that up to you to figure out